# What is the practical use of extension methods in Java?

Tags: c#, java, extension-methods

I understand C# extension methods, in that they allow you to add new methods to an already closed class definition. Java defender/extension methods seem to be something wholly different. For example:

```
public interface Interfacable {
    public void regular();
    public default void defender() { System.out.println("I am protected"); };
}
```

Okay, so I get that you can do 'trait-y' things with Java extension methods, but I don't see why it's called the same thing (an "extension") if it seems to uh, not do the same thing. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: That does not compile. There is Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) which sounds like what you want, but not that.

Comment: Should? Are you using Java-8?

Comment: No, Java 7 which is the last one released. If you want to discuss about Java 8, you should have specified that in the question.

Comment: Real programmers don't wait for official releases : ) . In all seriousness though, Java-8 is still Java, and obviously Java-7 doesn't have extension methods.

Comment: These two are very different features, each has its own benefits. At this time we still don't know the full extent of what Java's "default method" can be used for. C#'s extension method is obviously also very useful. Hopefully eventually Java will also copy C#'s feature, and C# will copy Java's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason these were added were part of the adding of closures to Java so that there was a easy upgrade path to things like collection classes. The challenge with the addition of closures is there now are a whole lot of functions you want to add to standard collections. However, if you add those to the existing interfaces you break any implementations of those interfaces.  A way around this is to add an additional interface with the new methods. This is possible without the virtual extension methods, however, it has its own drawback. Namely, that the implementation of that new interface needs to be added before it can be used.  Since there are probably a lot of implementations out there today it may take a long time to get all those implementations upgraded.  However, at the same time the way that the methods you want to add are pretty agnostic to the implementation.  They should do basically the same thing, at least in the base case.  The way the team that built this decided to handle the case was enable the specification of a default behavior that could be overridden. That way with the addition of the interface the functionality is there and it is up to the library writer decide it they want to write a different implementation.  The key is they don't have to, or there is a stop gap functionality until they do.

The long an short of it is they basically act like traits and you are correct they aren't the same thing as extension methods in C#.  From what I've read the original implementation of this was more C#.  However, the decision to use them that way because of the limitations of the style (i.e. unable to override the functionality) and lack of being able to use reflection do discover them.  It seems the name stuck, even though the approach to the implementation changed.

See the [write-up](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/Defender%20Methods%20v4.pdf) explaining Virtual Extension Methods for full details.

Comment: I think now it's simply referred to as "default method"